# How to apply equivalence matching using LIKE on Subject?

Tags: vba, filter, outlook

Following instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/how-to/search-and-filter/search-the-calendar-for-appointments-within-a-date-range-that-contain-a-specific), I'm trying to filter events in the Outlook calendar.

My code for reading the calendar and filtering by date:

```
    For Each oAppt In oItemsInDateRange
        Debug.Print Format(oAppt.Start, "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm"), oAppt.Subject
    Next
```

returns:

```
2020-08-03 00:00            WFH
2020-08-03 04:00            Heineken H1 Earnings
2020-08-03 08:00            Global Payments Q2 Earnings
2020-08-03 14:00            Global Meeting
```

But the filters for '%Earnings%' in the Subject this way:

```
    'Construct filter for Subject 
    Const PropTag  As String = "https://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/"
    strRestriction = "@SQL=" & Chr(34) & PropTag _
        & "0x0037001E" & Chr(34) & " like '%Earnings%'"
    Set oFinalItems = oItemsInDateRange.Restrict(strRestriction)
```

or this way:

```
    ' final using Jet
    strRestriction = "[Subject] = '%Earnings%'"
    Set oFinalItems = oItemsInDateRange.Restrict(strRestriction)
    oFinalItems.Sort "[Start]"
```

shows no results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The restriction URN is wrong. Try this filter:

```
strRestriction = "@SQL=" & _
        Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject" & Chr(34) & _
        " like '%Earnings%'"
```

I got the new URN from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/pia/how-to-filter-recurring-appointments-and-search-for-a-string-in-the-subject

Answer (score 0):

0x0037001E is `PR_SUBJECT_A`. Try `PR_NORMALIZED_SUBJECT_W` (DASL name `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E1D001F`)

Comment: Thank you, @Dmitry-Streblechenko. I've tried that and it did not work.

Comment: What was your query?

Answer (score 0):

try to remove the % , this is working for me.....

```
strRestriction = "[Subject] = 'Earnings'"
Set oFinalItems = oItemsInDateRange.Restrict(strRestriction)
oFinalItems.Sort "[Start]"
```

Comment: thanks @xShen, I tried that but it returns no items.